# how to create structure with data repeated in a certain period

Tags: php, mysql

I need to return data from two tables this way

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Name] => lorem,
        [Qty] => 2),
    [1] => Array(
        [Name] => ipsum,
        [Qty] => 1),
    [2] => Array(
        [Name] => dolor,
        [Qty] => 0)
    )
```

PHP will only take care of getting the data, there will be no manipulation to organize it.
Two tables, one to record a certain event, the date and the id of a table related to the event. And the tables are like this:

```
tableA
id |   date     | tableB_id
1    2020-10-02   2
1    2020-10-19   2
1    2020-10-21   1
1    2020-11-2    3
1    2020-11-11   1

tableB
id | name     
1    lorem
2    ipsum
3    dolor
```

And my SQL query

```
SELECT b.name as Name, a.created_at as created
FROM tableA b 
 INNER JOIN tableA a ON b.tableA_id = a.id WHERE MONTH(b.created_at) = '10' ORDER BY a.id;
```

which results in

```
Name | created
ipsum  2020-10-02
ipsum  2020-10-19
lorem  2020-10-21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Left Join TableA, but it irst need to have all the wanted rows as a subquery, to get also the 0  count

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tableA (
>   `id` int,
>   `date` date,
>   `tableB_id` int
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tableA
>   (`id`, `date`, `tableB_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1',    '2020-10-02'  , '2'),
>   ('1' ,   '2020-10-19'  , '2'),
>   ('1' ,   '2020-10-21'  , '1'),
>   ('1' ,   '2020-11-02' ,   '3'),
>   ('1' ,   '2020-11-11',   '1');
>
> CREATE TABLE tableB (
>   `id` int,
>   `name` varchar(19)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tableB
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1',    'lorem'),
>   ('2',    'ipsum'),
>   ('3',    'dolor');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT b.`name`, Count(`tableB_id`) 
> FROM tableB b LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM  tableA WHERE MONTH(`date`) = '10') a ON a.tableB_id = b.id
>  
> GROUP BY b.name
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | Count(`tableB_id`)
> :---- | -----------------:
> lorem |                  1
> ipsum |                  2
> dolor |                  0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=520358288ef6abc5a90bd7bf69999a7a)*

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't really thought about using LEFT JOIN. Actually, previously I tried to relate to INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next php code:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    name Name, COUNT(tableA.id) Qty
FROM tableB
LEFT JOIN tableA ON tableB.id = tableA.tableB_id AND MONTH(tableA.date) = 10
GROUP BY tableB.name;";

// get DB version using PDO
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($rows);
```

[Live PHP fiddle](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/8816db2a73c4624976c3c435561f982d/php/php8/d93982cf7a6b90bf284c282792b7ef7c/)

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => dolor
            [Qty] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ipsum
            [Qty] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => lorem
            [Qty] => 1
        )

)
```